# Error 500 on Joomla site

Tags: php, android, mysql, joomla

I have a really weird issue. I'm running a Joomla website which most of the time runs fine. But I am getting a few complaint mainly from people using Apple or Android devices saying they get an error 500 message. On most mobile devices it works fine. Sadly including mine and I cannot regenerate the error. No PC user complained about this.
I've checked every log file in existence, but there is no trace of an error. PHP error logging otherwise works fine. It is logging even notices.
I am using a mobile template but data is generated elsewhere, by the same code which generates data for the desktop version.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. I've run out of ideas...

I am running this on Ubuntu 14, PHP 5.5.9, MySQL 5.5.4. Joomla version is 2.5.27

Comment: Without any code, I doubt anyone will be able to help you. Also, just because no PC users have complained about it, doesn't mean that it doesn't exist on Desktop as well. Consider debugging your code further or adding some code that might be helpful for people trying to help you.

Comment: One thing to check is whether these users are coming to the site from a browser or from something like the Google search app.